# Url attribute to click <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a small problem with a small jQuery script. Basically, it is a url attribute if I click on a `<li>`. The problem is that if for example, I have links in this `<li>`, well I can not click on ..

Here is a small example : http://jsfiddle.net/St46x/1/

My script :

```
$('.listAgence').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).find('.infos').attr('href');
    $(location).attr('href',url);
});
```

Comment: You have to redirect the page on `http://stackoverflow.com` while clicking `icone2`?

Comment: what is `$(location)`

Comment: it is working on my Google Chrome when I click on the third li

Comment: Did you mean $(location) ==> location.href

Comment: The purpose of this this question is unclear

Answer (score 2):

Solution, prevent the default click on the other anchors and assume the bubbling click of the container "LI"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#liste li a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#liste li').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).find('.icone2').attr('href');
        location.href = url;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/St46x/5/

After clearing what you want, the solution would be (Prevent only if the link has no URL):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#liste li a').click(function(e){
        if ($(this).prop('href') == "")
            e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#liste li').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).find('.icone2').attr('href');
        location.href = url;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi roger, if i click on other link, the "activ <li> link" is first :(

Comment: Re, i've only link on my href. But example, if i have colorbox and i click on this, colorbox oppenning but after the link on <li> in activ, you know what i speak ?

Comment: @Stéphane say in your native language what you want, and I will translate that, its more easy that way.

Comment: Ok : Actuellement, si je clic sur un lien avec _blank ou un lien qui ouvre une popup, et bien il ouvre quand même lien. Je n'arrive pas à faire en sorte qu'il n'ouvre pas le lien si je click sur un href.

Comment: @Stéphane, Vous avez dit que le problème au début. Je pense qu'il serait plus facile de dire ce que vous comptez.

Answer (score 1):

$(location) is undefined. You can't use this code.

Try this:

```
document.location.href = 'www.google.com.tr'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 window.location.href = url;
```

instead of

```
 $(location).attr('href',url);
```